# How to write test for serialization and deserialization which involves javafx file chooser?

Tags: java, javafx

I need to write unit tests for serialization() and deserialization() functions which I've no idea how to cover FileChooser and FileInputStream.

And also, if there are two functions in this file, I must write two and only two corresponding test functions?

The two functions are as followings:

```
/**
 * serialize and save all the datasets and charts
 * @param myDataset
 *          pass all the existing datasets into this function for serialization purpose
 * @param myChart
 *          pass all the existing charts into this function for serialization purpose
 */

public static void serialize (HashMap<String, DataTable> myDataset, HashMap<String, Chart> myChart) {

    // first, let the user select a directory to save
    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    chooser.setTitle("Save");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("comp3111 type", "*.comp3111");
    chooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
    File file = chooser.showSaveDialog(new Stage());

    try {
        FileOutputStream fOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream objOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(fOutput);

        // put all the DataTable type objects into an array         
        objOutput.writeObject(myDataset);
        objOutput.writeObject(myChart);

        objOutput.close();
        fOutput.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


/**
 * choose a file with *.comp3111 extension for deserialization purpose
 * @return
 *          the chosen *.comp3111 file
 */
public static File deserialize () {
    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("comp3111 type", "*.comp3111");
    chooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

    File mfile = chooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());           
    return mfile;
}
```

Comment: Are `myDataset` and `myChart` domain classes or JavaFX classes? Because you *shouldn't* serialize JavaFX classes for persistency.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have code in your `serialize` and `deserialize` methods that doesn't belong there. They are too broad: not only do they serialise and deserialise objects (although the code for deserialisation appears to be missing), they also open file choosers.

While this may make sense from a program flow point of view, it also breaks the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (note: I'm aware that SRP is usually applied to a class and not to a method). Your methods do too many things.

So you should write your methods in such a way that they accept a `File` or `InputStream` as an input parameter, and return a collection of objects as a result (for deserialisation), or take a collection of objects and return an `OutputStream` as a result (for serialisation). That way, you can test exactly that behaviour.

Even better would be to first write the test, where you could for example use a test file, both to read from to check if it produces the expected objects, or you test that a `ByteOutputStream` returned by the serialiser matches that same file.

It's called [test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), and it's a good way to write testable and stable code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! advice taken!